# How to restore Isis template and see it in Extensions->templates

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am trying to restore the Isis template. I have reinstalled the zip file from Git. I can see the Isis folder and all of it's files under Administrator/templates, BUT I cannot see it in the Admin console under Extensions->templates->templates. After many years I want to use the template properly to customize the css of the backend of my site.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try clicking the discover button at `Extensions -> Manage -> Discover` and then select and install the template if it is discovered.